# How to allow free users to search songs via Spotify's iOS SDK/Web API in Swift?

Tags: ios, spotify

For my app, if one person logs into via Spotify with a premium account is there a way I can allow other users that use my app to search songs via the single premium account? (not for streaming, just for the sake of searching songs). I understand Spotify allowed free users to do this before but they made a change i believe in May of 2017 that prevents free users to search Spotify via their Web API. Any work arounds to this?

Comment: Most likely not. I'm no attorney, but this seems like a violation of [Spotify's Terms of Use](https://www.spotify.com/us/legal/end-user-agreement/#s4)

Comment: @Aaron I don't think it is as long as the free users are just using it to use Spotify's search and not stream music because there is an app store that allows one person to log into Spotify and others to search based on, I am assuming, the single person's Spotify Auth token. The app is called Partify.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that.
How much investigation have you done on the iOS API?

Comment: @Aaron Well there's two different Spotify tools I can use. Spotify's iOS SDK and also Spotify's Web API. I successfully implemented the Spotify iOS SDK to allow Spotify Login/Authentication which logs the user in and authenticates them with Spotify. Once authenticated, the user gets a Spotify Authentication token that lasts to my understanding 1 hour. From my reading of Spotify's Web API documentation, searches can be done with a Spotify Authentication token. I was thinking just sharing this string for the free users and they will be able to search the Web API with the token.

Comment: Cool. (that'd be good info to edit into your post to be more visible to others.) Do you need to logout and login again to get another token, or can you perform another auth of some sort to get another token or extend its life? If I am understanding you correctly, you are able to have free users make shared searches, but are stuck on the 1-hour limit?

Comment: @Aaron To be honest, i think i solved my own question with my previous response

Comment: Haha, wonderful! Double-check of course, but if it ends up working, you could post your own answer and accept it so others can benefit :)

Comment: @Aaron Okay will do thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to search for songs using Spotify's web API, you don't need any users involved at all. Just use the [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow). You can also use the library I created for the Spotify web API: https://github.com/Peter-Schorn/SpotifyAPI